# NSURLConnection post request stops posting after some time

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest

I am trying to post some values to my web service which is working for android version nicely and for iOS it works for about 12 requests then it stops sending. What am i doing wrong?

I am sending about 1 per second.

```
-(void) PostDataToServer:(NSMutableArray*) value
{
    NSString *xValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [value objectAtIndex:0]];
    NSString *yValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [value objectAtIndex:1]];
    NSString *jsonRequest = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"person\":\"%@\",\"x\":\"%@\",\"y\":\"%@\",\"z\":\"%@\"}",@"1",xValue ,yValue ,@"0.0"];
    NSLog(@"Request: %@", jsonRequest);

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"mywebserviceURL"];

    request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
    NSData *requestData = [NSData dataWithBytes:[jsonRequest UTF8String] length:[jsonRequest length]];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [requestData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setHTTPBody: requestData];
    NSData *urlData= connection= [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    NSLog(urlData);
```

Comment: how are you calling this method?

Comment: like that 

[self PostDataToServer:value];

Comment: You say that you are sending 1 per second. How are you sending 1 per second? Please edit your question to include the entire method where you call `[self PostDataToServer:value]`.